# Check for areas that are too thin in an image

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to validate black and white images (more of a clipart images - not photos) for an engraving machine.
One of the major things I need to take into consideration is the size of areas (or width of lines) since the machine can't handle lines that are too thin - so I need to find areas that are thinner than a given threshold.

Take this image for example:

[image]

The strings of the harp might be too thin to engrave.

I am reading about Matlab and OpenCV but image processing is an area I am learning about for the first time.

I am a Java / C# developer so implementation done with one of those languages will be best for me but any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately you seem to be asking for too much in one go. It may be better to start your work with some simpler exercises, and maybe ask some more direct questions about them as you learn about image processing (including code and explanations about what you are having trouble with).

Comment: I think the question is actually relatively well formulated. The OP posted a question that can be answered in an abstract computer vision way and pointers to appropriate algorithms or methods would qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A solution using [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) utilizing image [morphological operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/morphology-fundamentals-dilation-and-erosion.html#f18-24720):

Define the minimal thickness of allowed area, for example, `minThick=4`

```
BW = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXKep.jpg'); 
BW = BW(:,:,1) < 128; %// convert image to binary mask
se = strel('disk', minTick/2, 0); %// define a disk element   
eBW = imerode( BW, se ); %// "chop" half thickness from mask
deBW = imdilate( eBW, se ); %// dilate the eroded mask
```

Eroding and dilating should leave regions that are thicker than `minThick` unchanged, but it will remove the thin areas

```
invalidArea = BW & ~deBW; %// pixels that are in BW but not in deBW
```

Resulting with:
[image]

You can read more about [`imdilate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) and [`imerode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) in the linked documentation.

Comment: This is a great(!) example - I will be sure to take a look at it. How would one implement this matlab program in a real world application (Java/C#/Python etc.)?

Comment: @JamesBlack since we are only using extremely basic operations like `erode` and `dilate` you should have no problem find their equivalent in other programming languages: e.g., [opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html), [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_erosion)...

Comment: @Shai - Could you perform the same operation with an opening (`imopen`), as an opening is the same as an erosion followed by a dilation? +1 btw.

Comment: @rayryeng I tried to stick to the basics here and make the answer as simple and as clear as possible. You are correct that it can be done in other ways as well

Comment: @Shai - Was just curious :) Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Shai - I have posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395092/find-areas-that-are-too-thin-in-an-image-but-arent-an-end-of-a-pointy-shape) that I will appreciate if you take a look at.

Answer (score 5):

This is primarily for self-containment, but this is the equivalent code to what @Shai has performed in Python.  I used the [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) and [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_table_of_contents_setup/py_table_of_contents_setup.html) packages from Python.  The equivalent code to doing it in Python would simply be this:

```
import numpy as np # Import numpy package
import cv2 # Import OpenCV package

orig = cv2.imread('oXKep.jpg') # Read in image from disk
BW = orig[:,:,2] < 128 # Threshold below 128 to invert image
minThick = 5 # Define minimum thickness
se = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (minThick,minThick)) # define a disk element
finalBW = 255*cv2.morphologyEx(BW.astype('uint8'), cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se) # "chop" half thickness from mask and dilate the eroded mask

# Find invalid area
invalidArea = 255*np.logical_and(BW, np.logical_not(finalBW)).astype('uint8') 

# Show original image
cv2.imshow('Original', orig)

# Show opened result
cv2.imshow('Final', finalBW)

# Show invalid lines
cv2.imshow('Invalid Area', invalidArea)

# Wait for user input then close windows
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

A few intricacies that I need to point out:

1. OpenCV's `imread` function reads in colour channels **in reverse order** with respect to MATLAB.  Specifically, the channels are read in with a blue-green-red order.  This means that the first channel is blue, the second channel green and third channel red.  In MATLAB, these are read in proper RGB order.  Because this is a grayscale image, the RGB components are the same so it really doesn't matter which channel you use.  However, in order to be consistent with Shai's method, the red channel is being accessed and so we need to access the last channel of the image through OpenCV.
2. The `disk` structuring element in MATLAB with a structure number of 0 is essentially a diamond shape.  However, because OpenCV does not have this structuring element built-in, and I wanted to produce the minimum amount of code possible to get something going, the closest thing I could use was the elliptical shaped structuring element.
3. In order for the structuring element to be symmetric, you need to make sure that the size is odd, so I changed the size from 4 to 5 from Shai's example.
4. In order to show an image using OpenCV Python, the image must be at least an unsigned 8-bit integer type.  Binary images for display using OpenCV are not supported, and so I artificially made the binary images `uint8` and multiplied the values by 255 before displaying them.
5. You can combine the erosion and dilation operations into one operation using **morphological opening**.  Opening seeks to remove thin lines or disconnect objects that are thinly connected but maintain the shape of the original more larger objects.  This is the the point of eroding first so that you can remove these lines but you will shrink the objects a bit in terms of the area, then dilating after so that you can restore the shapes back to their original size (mostly).  I exploited that by performing a morphological opening via [`cv2.morphologyEx`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#morphologyex).

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: I have posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395092/find-areas-that-are-too-thin-in-an-image-but-arent-an-end-of-a-pointy-shape) that I will appreciate if you take a look at.