# Find areas that are too thin in an image but aren't an end of a pointy shape

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

This is a follow up question on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275352/check-for-areas-that-are-too-thin-in-an-image/28283747#28283747).
(Finding areas that are too thin using morphological opening on black and white images)
After reading and implementing the suggestions from [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28276163/4519424) and [rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28283747/4519424) I have another issue.
The algorithm also finds the end of pointy shapes and I need to disregard those since every triangle ends with a really thin area.

For example:
[image: Trident]

The algorithm finds the trident stick and the small part in the middle which is great. But it also finds the end of the trident at the top right which is the end of a shape.

Any ideas on how to identify those kind of cases will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you are working with raster images? Maybe instead of linking to the other question, you could make it more self contained, so people don't have to read the other one. It might also help if you explained why the thin parts are actually a problem, so we get better criteria for which parts to find.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using [`bwmorph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html#bui7b_c-1) operation `'endpoints'` applied to `'skel'` of your template - these two morphological operations should help you identify the the "pointy" shapes of your input image, thus excluding them from your "thin regions" you highlight.

Using opencv, you may find [this](https://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/getting-the-skeleton-of-a-binary-image-in-python/) example of morphological skeleton operation useful. It would also seems like [`pymorph`](https://pythonhosted.org/pymorph/index.html#pymorph.endpoints) can prove useful for you.